I want the DropDownButtonFormField to having padding/margin around it's DropDownMenuItems
I am using DropDownButtonFormField in my code. I want to add margin around it's items but am not able to do so. Here is my code:
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null) {
                        return AppStrings.pleaseSelectYourGender;
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
                    // value: _selectedGender,

                    items: [
                      AppStrings.male,
                      AppStrings.female,
                      AppStrings.other
                    ].map((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: SubText1(text: value, color:  AppColors.textColor,),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedGender = newValue!;
                      });
                    },
                    decoration:  InputDecoration(
                      labelText: AppStrings.selectGender,
                      labelStyle: AppStrings.labelStyle,
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: AppColors.fieldColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                      //border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: const  OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: const  OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      // errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      //   borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      // ),
                      disabledBorder:  const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

The result I want is:

My layout is:

I want the DropDownMenuItems to be aligned with the textfields above.

Check this package https://pub.dev/packages/animated_custom_dropdown

Refer my answer here and here for more, or use dropdown_below package

Use Padding
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: AppSizes.of(context)!.sizes.defaultButtonBorderRadius,
                    ),
                  ),
                  value: state.group.value.getOrElse(() => _iconName),
                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _iconName = value ?? '';
                    });
                    if (value != 'navigation_empty_icon'){
                      // print('strSelectedShipment-$strSelectedShipment');
                    }
                    notifier.groupChanged(value ?? '');
                  },
                  items: arrGroup,
                ),
              ),


this will not gonna work. i have already tried it.

Can you share your complete code for that form.

1-DropdownButtonFormField has a property called: contentPadding and it is inside of InputDecoration property, you can use it like this :
DropdownButtonFormField(
decoration: InputDecoration(
contentPadding:const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 12),));
2-for the child item (DropdownMenuItem) you can add padding for each widget.

contentPadding will add padding to the labelText. it will not achieve my desired result. what i want is that after clicking the DropDownButtonFormField the menu item have horizontal margin. you can see my provided screenshots above

As of my knowledge using DropdownButtonFormField we can't achieve it. we can make it by our own using overlay widget and some extra codes but it's a lot of work.
I found a package Drop Down 2 in pub.dev, you can use it to achieve the same much easier.

So i found a solution but you will need to modify it as per your requirement. For your requirement you can use another widget DropdownMenu. Following is the code to get you started. I have tested it.
 SizedBox(
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: DropdownMenu<String>(
              expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
              alignmentOffset: Offset.zero,
              controller: _genderController,
              initialSelection: null,
              hintText: "Select gender",
              inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
                filled: true,
                border: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white60.withValues(alpha: 0.3)),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                ),
                fillColor: Colors.white60.withValues(alpha: 0.3),
                focusColor: Colors.white60.withValues(alpha: 0.3),
              ),
              menuStyle: MenuStyle(
                backgroundColor: WidgetStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white60.withValues(alpha: 0.3)),
              ),
              dropdownMenuEntries: <DropdownMenuEntry<String>>[
                DropdownMenuEntry(value: "Male", label: "Male", style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white60.withValues(alpha: 0.3),

                )),
                DropdownMenuEntry(value: "Female", label: "Female", style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white60.withValues(alpha: 0.3),
                )),
                DropdownMenuEntry(value: "Other", label: "Other", style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white60.withValues(alpha: 0.3),
                  enabledMouseCursor: MouseCursor.defer
                )),
              ]
            ),
          ),

